# Read a string from a file with a dynamic name in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

My test plan contains a thread group that looks like that :

- Only once controller : Login to application

  - CSV Data Set Config : Info used to login to application
  - Only once controller

    - HTTP Request : POST login information
  - Loop controller (10 times)

    - HTTP Request : POST add a "comment" to a "question"

My CSV dataset contains these fields :

- username
- password
- group_id

A user have access to a question depending on it's group_id. I want to add 10 comments per thread to different questions.

My idea was to build a file like `questions_by_group_${group_id}.txt` containing some ids of questions that the `${group_id}` would have access. Then I could do `${__StringToFile(questions_by_group_${group_id}.txt)}` in the POST parameter value to add a comment. Using `__StringToFile` function should loop through lines of my file at every call. That way I can add many comments to many different questions.

The problem is that JMeter seems to open the file one time and share it for every thread (even thought I know that the `${group_id}` changes for every thread.

I tried many things like

- `${__StringFromFile(questions_by_group_${group_id}.txt)}`
- `${__StringFromFile(${__eval(questions_by_group_${group_id}.txt)})}`
- `${__eval(${__StringFromFile(${__eval(questions_by_group_${group_id}.txt)})})}`

but nothing works.

Comment: I suggest you ask your question on jmeter user mailing list, maybe someone has better ideas than mine.

Comment: Did you test my options ? Any feedback ? Thanks

Comment: I didn't test your option because I have many questions (50 to 100) and I think your solution would not "scale" to my need. 

Also, I wanted to iterate through questions at each loop, so I really don't know how to maintain a counter of column number in your solution.

Because I'm lazy, I decided to use only one question per user and put it in the CSV.

Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1):

StringFromFile works this way by default, read:

- [__StringFromFile](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile)

You could organize your csv like this:

- username, password, group_id , commentID1, commentID2....

Then put CSV Data Set Config before Once Only Controller.

Set Sharing Mode to All threads for example.

Finally just use variables instead of using __StringFromFile.

It's not the best solution as you have to build this file and repeat group_id ids.

Another option, if your number of groups is not very big, would be to do this in a [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group):

- read a CSV file containing:

  ```
    groupID1, IDA1, IDA2,....
    groupID2, IDB1, IDB2,....
    ...
  ```
- set one property per group [__setProperty](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) or calling this inside a Beanshell Sampler:

  ```
  JMeterUtils.setProperty(propertyName, propertyValue);
  ```

Then in your controller, use a Beanshell Sampler to get ids using:

```
    JMeterUtils.getProperty(propertyName);
```

I must say I hate all these solutions :-)

Comment: The issue is: I want to add many comment to many questions. Questions aren't accessible to all users. Files contains ids of questions by group_id. When I use __StringToFile in a POST parameter value, it uses  only the first file it opens.